# Odoo 16 on Nginx: can not enter editor mode after enabling TLS

Tags: nginx, proxy, odoo

Odoo doesn't work as expected after enabling TLS on Nginx (Ubuntu 22.04). When I click on the editor button on Website or eLearning section, the browser keeps on waiting with the running circle.

I have also tried adding `proxy_set_header Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-request;";` in the configuration file.

Comment: Please share more of your Nginx configuration. Also, a "running circle" is just an indefinite GUI indication of waiting for something. Take a look at the developer tools in your browser to figure out what resource(s) it is actually waiting and add that to your question, too.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.